# How to separate in columns the data contained in a barcode

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial, sd-card, datalogging

I have the following code, which allows me by scanning a typical 128 barcode to write this code in SD card under the Header "FA" as well as the time and date of scanner under the Header "Zeit".
I use for that an Arduino Uno, Waveshare scanner module connected in Serial to the arduino and SD/RTC mounted on top of the Arduino.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#define rxPin 2
#define txPin 3
RTC_DS1307 RTC;
SoftwareSerial mySerial = SoftwareSerial (rxPin, txPin);
File main_folder; // initialize folder for saving
File dataFile; // initialize sd file
const int chipSelect = 10; // CS pin on sd card module
int prev_file_indx = 0; // used for file naming
String fileName = "000";
char timestamp[30];



const unsigned int MAX_INPUT = 50; // how much serial data we expect before a newline

void dateTime(uint16_t* date, uint16_t* time) {
  DateTime now = RTC.now();
  sprintf(timestamp, "%02d:%02d:%02d %2d/%2d/%2d \n", now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second(), now.month(), now.day(), now.year() - 2000);
  // return date using FAT_DATE macro to format fields
  *date = FAT_DATE(now.year(), now.month(), now.day());

  // return time using FAT_TIME macro to format fields
  *time = FAT_TIME(now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
}


void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  mySerial.begin (115200);
  Wire.begin();       
  if (!RTC.begin()) {
    return;
  }

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
      return;
    }
    
    main_folder = SD.open("/");
    fileName = sd_saver(main_folder);

 // end of setup
    
    
    delay(1500);
    dataFile = SD.open("DATA"+fileName+".csv",FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    Serial.println(dataFile);
    Serial.println("Writing Headers...");
    dataFile.println("FA,  Zeit");
    dataFile.close(); // close the file
    Serial.println("File closed, Headers written");
  }
 }//Open-Create file , populatrd with headers (2 collumns)

void process_data (const char * data)//to process the incomingserial data (from Scanner + timestamp when scanned) after a terminator received
    
{ delay(500);
    SdFile::dateTimeCallback(dateTime);  
  DateTime now = RTC.now();
  sprintf(timestamp, "%02d:%02d:%02d %2d/%2d/%2d \n", now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second(), now.month(), now.day(), now.year() - 2000);
     dataFile = SD.open("DATA"+fileName+".csv",FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    Serial.println("Writing to file...");
    dataFile.print (data);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.println (timestamp);
    Serial.println (data);
    Serial.println (timestamp);
    Serial.println("Done.");
    dataFile.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
    delay(1000);
  }

}



void processIncomingByte (const byte inByte) //Processsing of the incoming scanned data
{
  static char input_line [MAX_INPUT];
  static unsigned int input_pos = 0;

  switch (inByte)
  {

    case '\n':   // end of text
      input_line [input_pos] = 0;  // terminating null byte

      // terminator reached! process input_line here ...
      process_data (input_line);

      // i here reset the buffer for the next time
      input_pos = 0;
      break;

    case '\r':   // discard the carriage return
      break;

    default:
      // keep adding if not full and permit for a terminating null byte
      if (input_pos < (MAX_INPUT - 1))
        input_line [input_pos++] = inByte;
      break;

  }  // end of the switch

} // end of processIncomingByte

void loop() {
  delay(2000);


  // if serial data available, process it
  while (mySerial.available () > 0)
  processIncomingByte (mySerial.read ());
  mySerial.write(processIncomingByte);
  delay(1000);

  //possibility to do other stuff while testing digital?? ...

}  // end of loop



String sd_saver(File dir){
  while(true){
    // iterate all files to ensure no overwrites
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry){
      break;
    }
    // naming routine
    String entry_name = entry.name();
    if ((entry_name.substring(4,7)).toInt()>=prev_file_indx){
      prev_file_indx = (entry_name.substring(4,7)).toInt()+1;
      if (prev_file_indx>=100){
        fileName = String(prev_file_indx);
      } else if (prev_file_indx>=10){
        fileName = "0"+String(prev_file_indx);
      } else{
        fileName = "00"+String(prev_file_indx);
      }
    }
    entry.close();
  }
  return fileName;
}
```

[image: Resulting file logged in the SD card]

My question is, can you come up with a way or guidance on how I should redo the code so that allows me to split the information of the barcode in different headers? that is columns. So for example the number "10000" as shown in the image after "@" to be in logged in another column called "Machine Number" ? I tried to insert control characters in the barcode to be scanned , but they are not interpreted as such but as characters .

Any help or thoughts are most than welcome

Thanks

Comment: google `c++ parsing text data`

Comment: take a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: @hcheung before I delve into this function, assuming that "pch stands for recompiled header, would you tell me if this "precompiled header" is acknowledge by Arduino Library , do I need a new one?

Comment: It's possible that the code's author decided to abbreviate the variable name, which could mean is stands for "pointer to a char". If you search our site for `char * pch;`, there are a few example of the code adapted to work in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: @VE7JROthanks for your answer. You mean by your site: http://www.cplusplus.com/?

Comment: @Maximilian1988 - I'm not sure what you mean when you say "your site". I am not affiliated with cplusplus.com, or any other Arduino website, except for this one. You are free to use any code at cplusplus.com as long as you can get it to compile in the IDE you are using. Once you have mastered the language reference here https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/, and want to do advanced "things", generic C++ websites will be your friend.